# .htaccess redirect... got lost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to do something simple but got stuck!

I'm trying to call this:
`https://example.com/profile/?username&mref=username` OR `https://example.com/profile/?username`

and get here:

```
https://example.com/username
```

This doesn't work!

```
RewriteRule ^(profile/?.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC,B]
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts in your question. Could you please confirm if you are hitting link `https://example.com/username` in browser?

Comment: Is username a variable or constant ?

Comment: I am trying to open it in a Browser.

"username" is variable

Answer (score 0):

You might require this:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/?$ https://example.com/%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L,NC,QSD]
```

This redirects like this:

```
https://example.com/profile/?username => https://example.com/username


https://example.com/profile/?username&mref=username => https://example.com/username&mref=username
```

QSD|qsdiscard strips QUERY_STRING from the query. See apache2 [rewrite_mod](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply but it did not work! :( 

Keep getting "The page isn’t redirecting properly"...

Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi! Re-did a bunch of "server" stuff and this actually worked in the end! Thank you so much!